# SharePoint 2013 getting all webs url failing in a given site collection including root web using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, branding, app

Using JSOM I am trying to get the collection of all the webs(sub-sites) including the root web of a given site collection and apply theme. but the url isn't correct.

Follow code:

```
function getWebs()
{
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web(); 
   var site = context.get_site();
   var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
   var subWebs = rootWeb.get_webs();

   context.load(subWebs, 'Include(Url, ServerRelativeUrl,ParentWeb)');
   context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {  
         subWebs = subWebs.getEnumerator();
         while(subWebs.moveNext()){
            var subWeb = subWebs.get_current();
            var testUrl = subWeb.get_url();
            alert(testUrl);
         }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
   );   
}
```

Follow image from Project that have debug:
[image: debug image failed url]

Correct:
The expected is : https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/sub1

Incorrect:
The result is : https://domain-XX1634579846354987.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/sub1

And not apply theme for all subsite.

> note: this method is recursive.

Some idea about how to resolve this question?

Comment: Probably domain.sharepoint.com is a DNS alias for the load balancing server.

Comment: Its office 365. Elaborate your answer on how to achieve this in SharePoint online.

Comment: OK sorry I tought sharepoint.com was a server name in his network.  In this case domain-xxxxx must be the real server name of his sharepoint site.  SharePoint is returning the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct url (a subsite). From your debug image, it looks like you have apps. Apps in SP 2013 get their own site where the naming convention is ' https://domain-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/subsite1'

To exclude the app sites (example):

```
 while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      var newweb = webEnumerator.get_current();
      if (newweb.get_webTemplate() == 'APP')
         continue;

      var obj = {
           title: newweb.get_title(),
           url: newweb.get_serverRelativeUrl(),
      };
      window.console && console.log('Title: ' + obj.title + ' Url: ' + obj.url);
 }
```

Change your code in your debug image as:

```
while(subsitesweb.moveNext()) {
    var web = subsitesweb.get_current();
    var webTitle = web.get_title();
    if(webTitle && web.get_webTemplate() !== 'APP') {
       //web.set ...
       web.update();
       web.applyTheme(ColorPalleteURL, fontscheme, background, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: but this subsite1 not is app and exclude for apply branding, and not do as expected. Returned full url incorrect, i don't need serverrelativeurl, i cant use full url to create new context site and apply, but as the url is incorrect, throw error why url not found. i will open ticket for Microsoft reporting this error.

Comment: Apps in SP are essentially a subsite, so you'd need to exclude them when enumerating for subsites. See the updated answer. Also, the code you posted doesn't match your debug image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below on my online setup and it worked properly

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web(); 
var site = context.get_site();
var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
var subWebs = rootWeb.get_webs();

context.load(subWebs, 'Include(Title, Url, ServerRelativeUrl,ParentWeb)');
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {  
        for (var i = 0; i < subWebs.get_count(); i++) {
            var subWeb = subWebs.itemAt(i);
            console.log(subWeb.get_url());
        }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Comment: again Url not result as expected :/ when get sub site level 2 the url is incorrect.

Comment: example: rootweb -> subweb work fine

Comment: rootweb -> subweb -> subweb fail